# How to set application installed via flatpak as default aplication for some type of files?

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, application, defaults, flatpak

I have installed pycharm via flatpak on **linux Mint 21.1**. I want to open every `.py` file in the PyCharm application. But when I right click and choose "*open with other application*" PyCharm is not on the list.

How can I set PyCharm to be default app for `.py` files ?

Thank you for help

---

EDIT:

I found .desktop file in `/home/kacka/.local/share/applications/userapp-com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Professional.desktop-95N5X1.desktop` but when I try to set it up I get this:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: How do you open `PyCharm`? by clicking on an icon (using a desktop file)?

Comment: I open it using menu in the desktop dock. I pres "win" key a then write down "pycharm"

Comment: I believe you are using a desktop file and therefore it should appear in the list of apps when you select: *"open with other application"*. Run these commands and show what you get: `find ~/.local/share/applications -iname "*pycharm*"` and `find /usr/share/applications -iname "*pycharm*"`

Comment: Also try this: `find /var/lib/flatpak -iname "*pycharm*.desktop"` (if you don't get any output from previous commands)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I have edited my question with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to go to:

```
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/
```

where I found this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  105 Jan  7 13:28 com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Professional -> ../../app/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Professional/current/active/export/bin/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Professional
```

So I set up default aplication to:

```
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Professional
```

and now it works